# Nesting content from template in HAML tag from partial

Tags: ruby, haml, indentation, partials, middleman

## Problem

I have a partial, which contains HTML structure for repeating elements of FAQ entry.

`partials/_faqitem.haml`:

```
.question
    %a.faq-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "\##{item}"} 
        = data.faq[item].q
    %div{:class => "collapse", :id => "#{item}"}
        Text directly in partial
```

I am using it in my `faq.html.md.erb.haml` template:

```
= partial(:"partials/faqitem", :locals => { :item => "so" })
```

This properly renders HTML and inserts data from `data/faq.yaml`:

```
so:
  q: What is Stack Overflow?
  info: Some other info
```

The problem arises when I try to add more text back in my template, under `= partial` call. I can't nail proper indentation that would allow me to render text in template *inside* `div` tag, in the same way as "Text directly in partial" is rendered.

Example of nesting in the template:

```
= partial(:"partials/faqitem", :locals => { :item => "so" })
    Text in the template

= partial(:"partials/faqitem", :locals => { :item => "so" })
        Text in the template
```

Depending on the level of nesting, I get either one of these errors:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input y in partial\n", 0, false);end;_hamlout.buffer << _hamlout.f ^
```

or

```
The line was indented 2 levels deeper than the previous line.
```

Is there any way to add text directly in the template in a way that will be rendered in the same way as if it would be nested inside tag from the partial?

---

### Specific example

To better illustrate desired result, here is an example.

`faq.html.md.erb.haml` template:

```
= partial(:"partials/faqitem", :locals => { :item => "so" })
    This is some text in the template.
    :markdown
        Now a *little* markdown to complicate things and then I will insert some information from data file, because I don't want to repeat myself.
    = data.faq.so.info
```

This, used with `partials/_faqitem.haml`:

```
.question
    %a.faq-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "\##{item}"} 
        = spanmarkdown(data.faq[item].q)
    %div{:class => "collapse", :id => "#{item}"
```

Should produce the same result as if the content from template was placed directly inside partial:

```
.question
    %a.faq-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "\##{item}"} 
        = spanmarkdown(data.faq[item].q)
    %div{:class => "collapse", :id => "#{item}"}
        This is some text in the template.
        :markdown
            Now a *little* markdown to complicate things and then I will insert some information from data file, because I don't want to repeat myself.
        = data.faq.so.info
```

Comment: Are you looking for `yield`?

Comment: So do you want this text to appear as if it was inside that partial? Why don't you just add it inside the partial?

Comment: @MaximFedotov I want text appear inside "div" tag, which is defined in partial. I can't add text directly to partial, as I will be re-using this partial with different text. And this different text will combine plain text with information sourced from different parts of data file.

Comment: So just a plain div after `.question`?

Comment: @TomLord No, I don't think ``yield`` would work in this case. I think it only makes sense in layouts.

Comment: @MaximFedotov As far as I can tell you copied my example, with exception of new lines. But yes, something like this would work as long as "Text directly in partial" would be replaced with whatever I placed in my template ``faq.html.md.erb.haml`` after calling partial.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this syntax, I always use `render` to render my partial and indentation works just fine. Why not just do this:

```
= render "partials/faqitem", item: "so"
%div
  Text in the template
```

Comment: Div has to have class and and id, hence ``{:class => "collapse", :id => "#{item}"}`` part in my example after div. And since ``id`` is the same as  ``item``, I want to pass it as local variable to partial, instead of repeating it in code. In your example, div is written after partial, not inside of it.

Comment: I edited my question to include the example of the specific case and its desired output.